# Declaration of control type

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder why this piece of code returns a type mismatch error whenever the UserForm is initialized:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize ()

    Dim F as MSForms.Frame

    For Each F in Me.Controls
        F.Visible = False
    Next F

End Sub
```

Comment: `F` will be a control in the way you have the loop.  You need to dim F as control and then look at it's type

Comment: Not each control is frame

Answer (score 3):

In support of my comment, something like so

```
Dim c As Control

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is Frame Then
        c.Visible = True
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Thank you! I just want to avoid declaring F as control because I have various types of controls and not all of them hold same properties.